# Javamail not connecting

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Trying to use JavaMail for the first time. Upon putting in details it prints true (as if it were connected), but when trying to find a folder, it doesn't work.

```
private static void login() throws MessagingException {
    String host = "imap.gmail.com";
    String username = "user@gmail.com";
    String password = "password";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    session = Session.getInstance(props);
    store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(host, 993, username, password);
    System.out.println(store.isConnected()); //THIS HERE RETURNS TRUE
}

public static void check()
{
    try {
        //create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX"); //ENDS PROGRAM LOGGING, "Not Connected"
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        javax.mail.Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            javax.mail.Message message = messages[i];
            if(message.getSubject().contains("Optimism") && message.getSubject().contains("New reply to watched thread")) {
                for(Guild g : jda.getGuilds()) {
                    if(g.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Optimism"))
                    for (TextChannel c : g.getTextChannels())
                        if (c.getName() == "staff_chat") {
                            c.sendMessage("**New Thread Reply! - " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + " EST.").queue();
                        }
                }

            }

        }

        //close the store and folder objects
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everthing in the if statement from the first loop all works

NOTE: It's in two methods as the check method is called every 2 mins.

Comment: what is `jda` represents here ? May be some problem with this

Comment: What happens if you do the `println(store.isConnected())` in the `check()` method, where it's more relevant?

Comment: @Sanjeev jda is part of another api I'm using for discord (you may have heard of it).

Comment: @Andreas returns true, however when I receive an email it says not connected and then suddenly returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, that `check()` method is getting called every two minutes. It will create problem as you are closing your store object in it `store.close()` . So it will work just the first time and after that it won't.

Either you call `login()` also every two minutes just before `check()` or do not close store in check and leave it open/connected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, and you can't expect to stay connected forever, so you'll need to handle that case as well.

Comment: Agree ... this has to be a timed connection.

Comment: I ended up putting them all in one method to see if it worked and it did. Thank's for clarifying why that would work.

Comment: Would it be more resource efficient to keep it open and close when the program closes?

Comment: As your re-connect time is 2 minutes, i would suggest to establish connection everytime before reading inbox folder.